# Angular scope variable not saved when using browser back button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AugularJS controller that have something like the following when initialized

```
$scope.urlChanged = false;
and the url is like /firstpage/test
```

There is a button in the page and when user clicks the button, the following is executed

```
$scope.urlChanged = true;
window.location = '/secondpage/test';
```

The page goes to /secondpage/test as expected. When clicking the browser back button, the page goes back to `/firstpage/test`. But the `$scope.urlChanged` is `false`, not the final value true. Is this expected in Angular? How do I make `$scope.urlChanged = true` when going back?

Comment: Did you try $location?  By accessing 'window' you bypassed Angular and on the 2nd page it's like a fresh reload.  See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: are you sure what this pice of code working , i mean you tried to put debugger in that line ?

Comment: Both of the pages make server call. It seems the problem is caused by not making the server call in both IE and Firefox. Chrome is ok.

Comment: I looked at the $location service. But I couldn't make the change from /firstpage/test to /secondpage/test. After some searching, I made the following change so that the server call will be made for all browsers. Not sure whether there is any simpler way to do that. '$browser.url(fullUrlForSecondPage);
$window.location.href = '/secondpage/test';'

Answer (score 2):

Scope variables are not saved when you navigate. In fact not even services will retain their values/state. When you navigate with browser back you actually request a whole new angular app.

This is not angular's fault. That is how the browser is expected to handle a new request. The way to persist data in this case is saving any data in something that will persists between requests.

As i see it you have three(ish) options:

1. Save state in cookies: Well supported by almost all browsers but take caution to handle them as clientside cookies or you won't be able to save data on a page you did not submit (excatly your problem with navigate back in browser).
2. Save server-side. This has the same problems as the server side cookies. You need to post data to the server for it to persist - which you *could* do with ajax calls and 'auto-save' with a timeout function. You also need a way of tracking who you are so you can get the correct data from the server - which is often done with cookies, but can be done with querystring parameters but also with (basic) authentication.
3. LocalStorage. This is my favorite option and is pretty well supported, if you don't need to support legacy IE browsers. There are good frameworks designed for angular that makes it easy to use - and some even have fallback to cookies if not supported.

Check out this link for LocalStorage support:
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

On change of view,new controller comes into picture and the previous view's controller's instance gets finished. Also , as every controller has its private scope which gets destroyed once view is changed to avoid confusion.